# OSX kill processes by port except PIDs

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, scripting

I want to kill all processes listening to port

```
kill -kill `lsof -t -i tcp:3000`
```

Now the problem is I want to exclude certain PIDs, -p option is not working for me.

```
kill -kill -p `pidof chrome` `lsof -t -i tcp:1337`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage a `while` loop here:

```
cpid=$(pidof chrome) && lsof -t -i tcp:3000 | while read pid; do \
     [[ $cpid != $pid ]] && kill "$pid"; done
```

Getting the PID of `chrome` is variable `cpid` and then iterating over the output of `lsof -t -i tcp:3000`, and if the PID doesn't match the chrome's PID then `kill`-ing the process.